# MonetDB set specific embedded python version

Tags: monetdb

In a Linux environment, I'd like to be able to set the embedded python3 to a specific python version. My current monetDB install seems to use `3.7` even though all default python paths point to `3.8.6`.

Is there a way to set my `3.8.6` install as the default embedded python3 version?

Comment: Could you please let us know which version of monetdb you have, and how you installed it?

Comment: Running inside a linux-based docker container, installed using the latest version found at https://dev.monetdb.org/downloads/deb/ along with the following apt packages monetdb5-sql monetdb-client monetdb-python3

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I am not very familiar with docker unfortunately. Is it possible that inside the container there is a python `3.7` installed? I will play around with this kind of scenario tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: I was looking more closely through my docker build and found that python3-dev was installing python 3.7. I will try to remove it and see if that resolves the issue. It is odd that monetDB wants that specific version though, as I am using a 3.8 container with 3.8 as default on everything. Appreciate you looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, the problem seems to be the following: because you are installing MonetDB using `apt`, the installation pulls the python version that the distribution has packaged in `apt`. I assume that you are building your container starting from `python:3.8`. This is based on [Debian Buster](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/c0333f552697fc1b94c760fabf9b0823a92f11a5/3.8/buster/Dockerfile) that packages [Python 3.7](https://packages.debian.org/buster/python3).

In a bit more detail:

I built a container using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

COPY ./monetdb.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
COPY ./MonetDB-GPG-KEY /
RUN apt-key add /MonetDB-GPG-KEY
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y monetdb5-sql monetdb-client monetdb-python3
```

with the files `monetdb.list` and `MonetDB-GPG-KEY` as described in the [downloads page](https://www.monetdb.org/downloads/deb/).

I then created a database farm and a new database in the container, setting `embedpy3` to true:

```
root@bd0420e945e8:/# monetdbd create /tmp/dbfarm
root@bd0420e945e8:/# monetdbd start /tmp/dbfarm
root@bd0420e945e8:/# monetdb create -p monetdb pytestdb
created database with password for monetdb user: pytestdb
root@bd0420e945e8:/# monetdb set embedpy3=yes pytestdb
```

Using `mclient` I created a Python UDF that returns as a string the version of the embedded python interpreter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pyversion () 
RETURNS STRING 
LANGUAGE python {
  import sys 
  return sys.version
};
```

When I called it I got the following result:

```
sql>select pyversion();
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| %2                                                  |
+=====================================================+
| 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44)              |
: [GCC 8.3.0]                                         :
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 tuple
```

I repeated the above process starting from a different distribution (Ubuntu Focal) that packages a different version of [Python](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python/python3) (It seems that Ubuntu has updated to Python 3.8.5 since the release of Focal).

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg ca-certificates

COPY ./monetdb.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
COPY ./MonetDB-GPG-KEY /
RUN apt-key add /MonetDB-GPG-KEY
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y monetdb5-sql monetdb-client monetdb-python3
```

In this container the function `pyversion` returns the following:

```
sql>select pyversion();
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| %2                                                  |
+=====================================================+
| 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40)              |
: [GCC 9.3.0]                                         :
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 tuple
```

In conclusion, I would suggest to either build MonetDB from source in the container (see the [README](https://github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB#building) for instructions), or build your container starting from a distribution that packages Python 3.8 in its package manager.